# Lag when changing imageview based on item's name in recycler view

Tags: android, imageview

I have a recycler view with cards that contain imageviews. The list of items consists of recipes, so I'm trying to change the ImageView at runtime checking if there's a drawable that corresponds to the recipe's name (I don't have an image for all the recipes in the drawable folder). If it doesn't exist, I set a generic image. Doing this causes Lags when scrolling the recycler view and sometimes it crashes when I try to press the back button. How can I make it smoother?

This is my code (RecyclerViewAdapter):

```
int test = ctx.getResources().getIdentifier(recipeName, "drawable", ctx.getPackageName());

    if(test != 0){
        imageView.setImageResource(test);
    }
    else{
        switch(item.getType()){
            case "Colazione":
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.colazione);
                break;
            case "Pranzo":
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.pranzo);
                break;
            case "Spuntino":
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.snack);
                break;
            case "Cena":
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.cena);
                break;
            case "Dessert":
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.dessert);
                break;
            case "Aperitivo":
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.brunch);
                break;

        }
```

When It crash it launches this exception :

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 83574412 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 42MB until OOM
```

Comment: please add your crash logs.

Comment: If it's a memory issue, you could perhaps try a library like Fresco, Glide, Picasso etc.

Comment: I've tried Glide ma it didn't solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

If your all drawables located in default **drawable** folder, resize and put them into drawable directories with the dpi qualifiers:

- drawable-mdpi
- drawable-hdpi
- drawable-xhdpi
- drawable-xxhdpi
- drawable-xxxhdpi

Otherwise, you can get memory errors for scaling processes. And avoid using very high resolution images. For example, if you show images only 100dp width, do not use higher than 300px for xxhdpi devices.(1dp = 3px for xxhdpi density)

> By default, Android scales your bitmap drawables (.png, .jpg, and .gif files) and Nine-Patch drawables (.9.png files) so that they render at the appropriate physical size on each device. For example, if your application provides bitmap drawables only for the baseline, medium screen density (mdpi), then the system scales them up when on a high-density screen, and scales them down when on a low-density screen. This scaling can cause artifacts in the bitmaps. To ensure your bitmaps look their best, you should include alternative versions at different resolutions for different screen densities.

[Source](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: Which size should I choose for mdpi, hdpi, etc ?